# MySQL 5.6 cannot backup database

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql

Using an up to date copy of Workbench client (v6.3.5 x64) on Windows, I was trying to create a dump file from my MySQL database, but always get only a 0~1Ko dump file. I've tried that on two servers with the same versions, I get the same result:

- Error executing task: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
- Error executing task [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\users\user.web\appdata\local\temp\2\tmpp0town.cnf'

[image]

[image]

This database is used by a local IIS website, I stopped the whole IIS service and tried again, the issue remains the same.

Previously I could get the dump files, as you can see in the file explorer screenshot below:

[image]

I thought that forcing Workbench to use the right version of Mysqldump tool would resolve the issue, so I went to Workbench Preferences: Edit -> Preferences -> Administration -> and entered the path to mysqldump tool file:"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe", but this did not resolve the issue.

I tried also to make dump file using command line, but failed:

[image]

I've double checked the password, it is the one I usually use to connect the MySQL instance on Workbench.

Does someone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Using MySQL Workbench 8.0 I have the same error as your first, except my `u'\xa3'` character is in position 4. We get that error because at the specified 0-based position in our password there is a `£` character. Did you know that at least [since 2011](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60276) MySQL Workbench [does not allow](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67701) a password to contain [non-ascii characters](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75212) when used to export/dump a database? We can consider it an established tradition at this point - as in, MySQL Workbench is a traditionally bad software and you should use something else entirely if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

1) Make sure you wrap paths and names that contain spaces with double quotes on the command line, otherwise those names may be interpreted as different parameters.

2) The error message in MySQL Workbench seems to indicate that you have data in your table that is not of the expected format. Check the table you are exporting and the data it contains. From the error it appears you have an ascii encoded column that contains non ascii characters. If that is the case you have first to consolidate your table such that either the encoding matches the content (i.e. convert the column or entire table to e.g. utf8) or you remove all content that doesn't match the expected encoding.

Comment: - 1) I have shorten the password, it seems to give issue with the last two characteres: "&W"   - 2) I have uninstalled any version of MySQL and erased their directories in Program Files folder, then reinstalled a new version and created a new database with 1 table and 1 row using utf8, the issue remains the same. I have remarked the next: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004591/mysql-5-5-cannot-connect-using-command-line-in-windows